# Confused with session and array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a session variable named `$_SESSION['items']` that is an array. It stores items in arrays, inside its array. For example:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 ) )
```

This show that there is 1 of product 2 in the items array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 1 ) )
```

This shows that there is 1 of item 2, and 1 of item 4 in the items array..

How so I check if a specific variable is in the items array? For example, i need to know if item 4 or item 1 is in this array so I can show the user a different page depending on if they have this item in their array or not. I get so confused with arrays that I always call undefined offsets and the like.

Comment: You'll need a loop, like foreach.

Comment: Read more about PHP arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $key => $item) { }` like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. had a brain fart. thanks

```
foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $key => $item) {
    if($item[0] == $item_id) {
        echo "ITEM IS IN HERE";
    }
}
```

//Try using array search good way

Comment: see the array_search optimized way

Answer (score 1):

Try following this will help you to get the position where found and return nothing if not found

You dont need to loop through.

```
// this will search $item_id in $_SESSION['items']
$key = array_search($item_id, array_column($_SESSION['items'], 0)); //here 0 is position, see array_search
print_r($key);
if($key){
//yes found at key so that you can easily get that item again without looping
}
```